# Azure Functions model binding issues in C#

Tags: c#, json, json.net, azure-functions

I want to use Azure Functions and have models automatically parsed as in typical ASP.NET WebAPI project.
So, I write:

```
[FunctionName("StartJob")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Start(
    [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "Post", Route = "v1/job")] StartJobRequestModel model)
{
    this.logger.LogInformation("StartJob function has been entered.");
}

public class StartJobRequestModel
{
    [JsonRequired]
    public string TenantId { get; set; }
    ....
}
```

So, you expect that if you don't provide required `TenantId` field, based on this code, during under-hood JSON de-serializing the program should not even enter the function body.
But what it does is:

Logs json deserializing error

> [2/10/2020 10:59:14 AM] Request successfully matched the route with name 'StartJob' and template 'api/v1/job'
>
> [2/10/2020 10:59:14 AM] JSON input formatter threw an exception.
>
> [2/10/2020 10:59:14 AM] Newtonsoft.Json: Required property 'tenantId' not found in JSON. Path '', line 16, position 1.
>
> [2/10/2020 10:59:14 AM] Executing 'StartJob' (Reason='This function was programmatically called via the host APIs.', Id=22be443b-9a70-4570-8a30-1cc9b8062f1b)
>
> [2/10/2020 10:59:16 AM] StartJob function has been entered.

And continue works without any problems with unexpected exceptions after not-expected model has been received...

The questions is:

1. Is it normal behaviour?
2. Maybe I need to specify some specific parameter in config of project or in Startup.cs?
3. Microsoft's bug?
4. ???
5. Not profit?

Thank you.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? 

I am currently sitting with the exact same issue.

Comment: @Nfourx hi, I use FluentValidator and have full control of it...

I may test new Azure Functions 5 in the future but I don't think it will be solved. Although, in the new functions you can already write your own middlewares and parse the stuff yourself...

Answer (score 0):

Not sure which version of NewtonSoft.Json you're, but usually I use JsonProperty attribute rather than JsonRequired attribute and it works as expected:

```
public class StartJobRequestModel
{
    [JsonProperty(Required = Required.Always)]
    public string TenantId { get; set; }
    ....
}
```

Comment: you can also use [JsonProperty(Required = Required.DisallowNull)]

Comment: Isn't it the same as JsonRequired?
Works the same for me, though...

Comment: The version is which is used by Sdk.Functions - 11.0.2

Comment: [JsonProperty(Required = Required.DisallowNull)] - this one even don't log the error when you don't provide the property...